# How to get the session ID of session in a remote machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, sessionid, powershell-remoting

I want to get the session ID of a user's session in a remote machine. I could achieve this through the command

```
$result = Query Session account17 /server:localhost
```

and

```
$result = qwinsta account17 /SERVER:localhost
```

But this is done locally.

But when trying to run the command on a remote session I am getting the error 'No session exists for account17', even if the user account17 is logged in. I am able to get the session of the user by performing the above command on the machine locally.

Is there a way to retrieve the session ID of a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that from WMI by the Win32_LoggedOnUser class, but you have to do some parsing to get it nicely:

```
gwmi win32_loggedonuser -ComputerName $computername |
foreach {
          [PSCustomObject]@{
             User = $_.antecedent -replace '.+Domain="(.+)",Name="(.+)"','$1\$2'
             Session = $_.dependent -replace '.+LogonID="(\d+)"','$1'
             }
        }
```

Or you can use CIM:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_loggedonuser -ComputerName $computername |
foreach {
          [PSCustomObject]@{
             User = $_.antecedent -replace '.+Name = "(.+)", Domain = "(.+)".','$2\$1'
             Session = $_.dependent -replace '.+LogonID = "(\d+)".','$1'
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Terminal Services PowerShell Module](http://psterminalservices.codeplex.com/)

```
PS> Get-TSSession -ComputerName server1 -UserName account17
```

Comment: I tried the command.I am getting the following error : 'The term 'Get-TSSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
he spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'

Comment: You need to download the module, load it. and then execute the command.